# Events, custom post type plugin in wordpress with elementor widget to display all Events

Tags: elementor, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am creating a custom plugin to create 'Events' custom post type which also adds a widget in Elementor

to display upcoming events. I have registered custom post type in main file of plugin which is custom-events-plugin.php. Elementor widget file is elementor-widget.php where I have added code of widget to display all Events similar to Elementor Pro 'Posts' Widget. Custom Post type is working fine in dashboard but the issue I am facing is that my custom Events Widget doen't show in Elementor Panel. I am posting the code of elementor-widget.php. Can anyone has a look and find the issue where I am going wrong.

```
<?php
// elementor-widget.php

class Elementor_Custom_Event_Widget extends \Elementor\Widget_Base {

    public function get_name() {
        return 'elementor_custom_event_widget';
    }

    public function get_title() {
        return esc_html__( 'Custom Event Widget', 'sufyanmuhammad.com/events' );
    }

    public function get_icon() {
        return 'fa fa-calendar';
    }

    public function get_categories() {
        return [ 'general' ];
    }

    protected function _register_controls() {
        $this->start_controls_section(
            'section_content',
            [
                'label' => esc_html__( 'Content', 'sufyanmuhammad.com/events' ),
            ]
        );

        $this->add_control(
            'number_of_events',
            [
                'label'   => esc_html__( 'Number of Events', 'sufyanmuhammad.com/events' ),
                'type'    => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::NUMBER,
                'default' => 5,
            ]
        );

        $this->end_controls_section();
    }

    protected function render() {
        $settings = $this->get_settings();
        $number_of_events = $settings['number_of_events'];

        // Query the custom post type
        $events_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type'      => 'event',
            'posts_per_page' => $number_of_events,
        ) );

        // Display the events
        if ( $events_query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $events_query->have_posts() ) {
                $events_query->the_post();
                ?>
                <div class="custom-event">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <p>Date: <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_event_date', true ); ?></p>
                    <p>Time: <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_event_time', true ); ?></p>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        } else {
            echo 'No events found.';
        }
    }
}

function register_custom_event_widget( $widgets_manager ) {
    $widgets_manager->register_widget_type( new Elementor_Custom_Event_Widget() );
}
add_action( 'elementor/widgets/register', 'register_custom_event_widget' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your need and what have you already tried, but just thought it would be best to point you to [Elementor's docs](https://developers.elementor.com/docs/widgets/add-new-widget/), explaining how to add new Widgets. If that's what you're trying to do, you should follow these docs.